# Using FirebaseUI with Twitter Login (iOS App)

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

In my IOS app I am using the FirebaseUI for all of my login authentications. I just installed the Twitter authentication provider and it logs in just fine but I am unable to find the twitter username or get an email address from the current user object. What's interesting is that the twitter username DOES appear on the Firebase Console > Authentication on the table under the identifiers column. This is a two-part question and specific to the FirebaseUI methodology of signing in.

1. Where in the Auth.auth().currentUser can I get the twitter username? If not there, how is it retrieved.
2. How do I get the twitter email address? This is not populated in the Auth.auth().currentUser object.

Here is the setup code for the twitter login capability.

```
authUI!.delegate = self

let emailProvider = FUIEmailAuth(...)
let twitterProvider = FUIOAuth.twitterAuthProvider()
authUI!.providers = [emailProvider, twitterProvider]

let authVC = authUI!.authViewController()
present(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the didSignInWith resulting code.

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) 
{
    if let auth = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        // do something now that user is logged in...
    }
}
```

The auth variable above is populated with the twitter user and I do see the auth.displayName value. The auth.email is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I didn't realize until diving into the docs that there was an additionalInfo in the response. So the code looks something like...

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else { return }
    if let auth = authDataResult?.user {
        if authDataResult?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser {
            let username = authDataResult!.additionalUserInfo?.username ?? ""
            let screenName = authDataResult!.additionalUserInfo?.profile?[screen_name] as? String ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

In the case of Twitter the username is empty but the screenName contains the user's Twitter name.